# Why can't I change my volume keybindings?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, shortcut-keys

My laptop's default sound adjustment keys are fn + up/down. In gnome 2.x I easily changed this binding to my keypad's upper right keys (/ and *). It seems that gnome 3 is allowing me to change the keybinding but when I press those buttons it still prints out the / and * symbols. It appears that nothing but the default media key bindings will register. Is this a bug I should report or is this intentional behavior by gnome?

I do know they block assigning regular keys for protection of losing keyboard functionality but in this case it does allow me to assign it, it merely doesn't work.

EDIT: I've found that the same thing happens under KDE as well. I believe that Gnome is not to blame. What is preventing these keys from registering their assigned actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change keybindings with a .xmodmap file in your home directory.
First you gotta open a terminal type `xev` and then the press desired keys (keys you want the behaviour of and keys you want this behaviour to have). Xev will record the keybindings giving you keycodes and names of commands. Then you go to you home directory and create a new file called `.xmodmap`. In there you have to arrange everything as the following example:

`keycode 110 = Home` (key you want to give = the desired command)

With this you can easyly swap or change keybindings. After that you have to log out and back in and choose the created .xmodmap to be used.

In the end it looks like this:

**keycode key1 = function key2**

**keycode key2 = function Key1**